# Liquibase boolean for Oracle and HSQLDB

Tags: xml, oracle, liquibase, hsqldb

I need to insert a new row inside both Oracle (for prod) and HSQLDB (for tests) with only one `<insert>`, but the boolean is what makes the problem - Oracle expects `1`, HSQLDB expects `true`.

Here is how I do it right now, but is it possible to remove the `dbms` and do it for both DBs with the same `<insert>`

```
    <insert dbms="oracle" tableName="MY_TABLE">
        <column name="ID" valueComputed="MY_TABLE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL"/>
        <column name="NAME" value="JOHN DOE"/>
        <column name="VISIBLE" value="1"/>
    </insert>
    <insert dbms="hsqldb" tableName="MY_TABLE">
        <column name="ID" valueComputed="MY_TABLE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL"/>
        <column name="NAME" value="JOHN DOE"/>
        <column name="VISIBLE" value="true"/>
    </insert>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you're asking, is this your question: How do I insert a new row in both our production Oracle and test HSQLDB databases with only one `<insert>` when Oracle wants the value for `"VISIBLE"` to be `"1"` and HSQLDB wants the value to be `"true"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `valueBoolean`. For example:

```
    <insert dbms="hsqldb" tableName="MY_TABLE">
        <column name="ID" valueComputed="MY_TABLE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL"/>
        <column name="NAME" value="JOHN DOE"/>
        <column name="VISIBLE" valueBoolean="true"/>
    </insert>
```

That will let liquibase know that the "true" string isn't the string to pass, but a boolean value that should be converted to whatever the target database uses for boolean values.